# WPF TextBox UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus keeps updating data

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, data-binding

I am making my way through a tutorial series for WPF. Currently I am at this step http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/responding-to-changes/

The problem I encountered is that I expect the Textbox to only update the value when I leave the TextBox. But even **wether im in or outside** the TextBox the value get's updated when I change the window size. That's not what I expect. Where is my error?

Here the short version of the code to test it yourself:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="Window dimensions: "/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Width, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="50" />
            <TextBlock Text=" x " />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Height, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="50"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: There is all right as it must be, just read more about [LostFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx). So when you change size, textbox lost it's `focus`, but not `keyboard focus`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But even if I'm inside the TextBox the value get's updated when I
>   change the window size.

You yourself said that while changing the window size, the value gets updated. It's because the focus is lost from the text box. You can programmatically set focus to the textbox if you want it to be focussed even after focus is lost.

The second textbox `<TextBox Text="{Binding Height, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="50"/>` also has `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. I hope it is not the case you're explaining, since `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` will update the source whenever a new character is entered into the textbox.

Comment: Of course it has to be "But even if I'm outside the TextBox ... didn't notice that one when posting I will update it immediatly

Comment: I'm confused. In one of 2 cases it shouldn't update. When I have focus or when I don't. But it keeps updating in both cases.

Comment: I have tested your code by putting break points. 
For the first textbox : The set is called only when focus is changed from the textbox.
For the second textbox : The set is called when a new character is entered into the textbox.

Comment: I understood the mechanism now. You gave me the hint. The TextBox updates the Window. My way of thinking was when I resize the window and I move the focus out of the first TextBox it should keep it's value but it never did. Wrong direction. Just tested it and now I understood it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The UpdateSourceTrigger works FROM the TextBox TO the binding control & property. So, I suppose that the first TextBox updates the property Width of the Window only when the focus is lost. The second TextBox updates the property Height of the Window at every value change. When you resize the Window, both TextBox are updated, because the source is the Window. UpdateSourceTrigger property works considering the TextBox as the source.

Comment: "So, I suppose that the first TextBox updates the property Width of the Window only when the focus is lost." Exactly that is what I expect it to do but it keeps doing it continuously. That's why I came to ask why. As it is not what I expect it to do.